# String contains function in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string variable which can have values something like $100 or $123-. I need to checked if the string has a '-'in it. If it has '-' I need to return ($123) otherwise just return $100.I know we can use string.contains function to see if '-' exists in the string but not sure how to remove '-' from it. I tried below but it is not working

```
public string convertNegativeAmountt(string n_amt)
{
  if(n_amt.contains(-)
   return "("+n_amt +")";
  else 
    return n_amt;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile... please post compiling code.. And it if is the compilation error that you have trouble with then say what it is (and what you've tried in order to solve it

Comment: try n_amt.Remove(n_amt.IndexOf('-'));

Answer (score 1):

```
public string convertNegativeAmountt(string n_amt)
{
  if (n_amt.Contains("-"))
     return "(" + n_amt.Replace("-", "") + ")";
   else
      return n_amt;**strong text**
}
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket... And the full stop should be a comma, and `Contains` method doesn't take operators.

Comment: Sloppy of me ... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IndexOf if its always and this would work assuming the `-` character is always expected as the last character.

```
public string convertNegativeAmountt(string n_amt)
{
    if (n_amt.IndexOf("-") > 0)
        return "(" + n_amt.Substring(0, n_amt.Length-1) + ")";
    else
        return n_amt;
}
```

Comment: No the Character `-` is always at the end like `$123-`

Comment: @trx - updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Just take the substring from the beginning of the string to the '-'

```
return "(" + n_amt.Substring(0, n_amt.LastIndexOf('-')) + ")";
```